# Can i use Client-based CORS Configuration with my own IClientStore?

Tags: cors, identityserver4

I created my own client store and made sure my clients all have this property set:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets the allowed CORS origins for JavaScript clients.
public ICollection<string> AllowedCorsOrigins { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to use Client-based CORS Configuration with my own IClientStore at all?

The [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/cors.html) say this will work out of the box if you use "in-memory” or EF-based client configuration. but what about with your own?

If this is possible could you give me an example please?

Comment: The next line of the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/cors.html): _If you define your own IClientStore, then you will need to implement your own custom CORS policy service._  --> From 'Custom Cors Policy Service': _The single method to implement is: `Task<bool> IsOriginAllowedAsync(string origin)`. Return true if the origin is
allowed, false otherwise._ For a sample, take a look at the [source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/src/EntityFramework/src/Services/CorsPolicyService.cs). Inject your custom copy _after_ AddIdentityServer().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ruard you were right i implemented that after seeing that the EF and the in memory version did the same thing. And ofcourse it works.